# Extremely small electric shock device - could this work?

Tags: timer

My question is this: Is it possible to build a device which could deliver a small electric shock every hour or so, and to fit this into a standard size ring?

I am talking about a small electric shock to the wearer - enough to be noticeable but not painful. An on/off switch could be added to the outside.

I am skeptical that a battery, timing chip aswell as well as the rest of the circuitry could be squeezed into that small a space and still deliver a noticeable shock. Battery life could also be a problem.

Can you think of a plausible way to do this?

Comment: Depends on how you define "standard size ring".

Comment: Given an average gold ring weight of 5g divided by density of gold gives an internal volume of 0.0158 in^3, even at the upper end of energy density (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_polymer_battery) 730 W·h/L gives you 0.189 Wh. Eletroshock wepons delever .9 to 10J of energy (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroshock_weapon), assuming a 1J shock you could theroiticaly delever 680 pulses before the "battery" is depleated, but i do not thing it would even be possival to get a shock ciruit in that small an area letalone use 100% of the space for batterys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as 'standard size ring'. It would be pretty easy to fit anything into a ring like this: http://www.mindwhatyouwear.com/bigring.html

Otherwise, the circuit will have to be a boost converter which will slowly charge the capacitor, which will then be quickly discharged into the finger. How big of a capacity are we talking about?
Well, this forum thread talks about being shocked by capacitors:
http://www.diyaudio.com/forums/everything-else/27768-danger-capacitor-electric-shocks.html
Based on this, I would choose, say, 120 volt and 0.1uF.

The biggest components circuit will need to have:

- Battery: MS412 is 4.8mm x 1.2mm:

[image: MS412 battery]

- 2x 200 volt mosfets: http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/EPC2012/917-1017-1-ND/2351743 is bare die, 1.6x0.8x0.8 mm
- 200 V capacitor: http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/C2012X7T2E104K125AA/445-7749-6-ND/2734459, 2x1.5mm
- Inductor -- if we do not care about efficiency, we can make a custom  inductor by winding wire over the part of the ring (which will have to be made of ferrite)

Our battery is 1mah. At 1% efficiency (reasonable given that the parts are not the best), we will get 
[1 milliampere * hour * 3 volt / (0.1 microfarad * (120 volts)**2) * 0.01](https://www.google.com/search?q=1%20milliampere%20*%20hour%20*%203%20volt%20%2F%20%280.1%20microfarad%20*%20%28120%20volts%29**2%29%20*%200.01&oq=1%20milliampere%20*%20hour%20*%203%20volt%20%2F%20%280.1%20microfarad%20*%20%28120%20volts%29**2%29%20*%200.01) = 75 shocks

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity - I meant a plain band type ring with rough dimensions of 2-3mm thick and 5-10mm wide. Something about this size: http://www.titaniumkay.com/images/Ring/P104121.jpg   As for the circuit, I am surprised that the components would be that small (other than the battery). It seems at though the main problem would be this battery - it's pretty large (relatively) and wouldn't deliver much power. Could a strip battery be wound around inside the ring, to make better use of space. Or could it be charged somehow to further the battery life? Thanks in advance.

Comment: One extra thing - would this just work a whole lot better in bracelet form?

Comment: As you know, li-ion batteries are made from the wound strip: http://www.tested.com/tech/1366-how-to-get-the-most-from-your-lithium-ion-batteries/, so potentially, you can repack a battery into roundish form. And yes, this will be rechargeable, otherwise there will not be much point in it.

Comment: It will work much better in a bracelet form -- plenty of space, and contacts are further apart from each other for stronger perceived shock.

Comment: Sounds like it could be possible then, thanks for your comments.